# Incorrect syntax near 'order' in insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server

So... I want to be able to insert the results of a query in a table.

```
SELECT top 30 dt ,  
count(*) AS NumberOfOrders 
FROM shoptable 
WHERE (name LIKE '%shop%') 
GROUP by dt ORDER by dt
```

This query successfully returns the number of orders per each day from previous days.

Now I want to insert this into a table called shop_stats and this is my query:

```
INSERT INTO shop_stats 
(dt, NumberOfOrders) 
(SELECT top 30 dt ,  
count(*) AS NumberOfOrders 
FROM shoptable 
WHERE (name LIKE '%shop%') 
GROUP by dt ORDER by dt)
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

If I remove the order by clause .... I will have 30 random days with orders.. not the last 30 as I need.

Does anybody know how to solve this in a relatively easy way? (i.e. no additional scripts that would remove the unnecessary data etc. - I just need a single SQL query).

Comment: loose the brackets: `insert into shop_stats (dt, NumberOfOrders) select top 30 dt ,  count(*) as NumberOfOrders from shoptable where (name like '%shop%') group by dt order by dt`

Comment: "the last 30 as I need" - if I interpret that as "the most recent 30 days" then, at the least, it should be `order by dt desc` rather than plain `order by dt` which would (when combined with `top 30`) give you the 30 earliest days in your sample data.

Comment: Yeah, the brackets are confusing it, it should just be `insert into <table> (<columns>) select ...`

Comment: I think however that the real question is why you are choosing only 30 days? I am assuming you run this every 30 days. To be more versatile it might be relevant to select the 'top 1' date from shop stats and then select all dates (datetime) > than this from the shoptable...code available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no intrinsic ordering of rows within the table - any specific ordering is supposed to be done when you're getting the data out, not when you're putting them in.
So, just remove the `order by` clause, insert them, and then order them again when you select them.

That, said, if you absolutely, positively, need to insert them in a specified order (as in your case), you can use a subquery with `top` clause

```
insert into shop_stats (dt, NumberOfOrders) 
select * 
  from (select top 30 dt, count(*) as NumberOfOrders 
        from shoptable 
        where (name like '%shop%') 
        group by dt 
        order by dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte (dt,numberoforders)
as
(
select top 30 dt,count(*) as NumberOfOrders from shoptable where (name
like '%shop%') group by dt order by dt
)
insert into shop_stats (dt, NumberOfOrders) select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no implicit ordering of rows in a table, there is an unusual extension for `order by` in insert.  If you do:

```
INSERT INTO shop_stats(dt, NumberOfOrders) 
    SELECT top 30 dt, count(*) AS NumberOfOrders 
    FROM shoptable 
    WHERE name LIKE '%shop%')
    GROUP by dt
    ORDER by dt;
```

And `shoptable` has an `identity`, `primary key` column, then the identity values assigned to the row are guaranteed to be in the order specified.  The rows may not be inserted in the table in that order, but the identity column respects the ordering.

This is hard to find in the documentation.  Unfortunately, almost all referencesin the documentation explain how this does not work with `select into`.  Here is one [reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

whenever you use `order by` clause within `() or brackets` is not working.

use below code, which is working fine.

```
insert into shop_stats (dt, NumberOfOrders) 
select * 
  from (select top 30 dt, count(*) as NumberOfOrders 
        from shoptable 
        where (name like '%shop%') 
        group by dt )
        order by dt
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new AUto Increment id on shop_stats table and then it will work.